# Use TransitionSet for enter/exit transition with android navigation library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to use `TransitionSet` in combination with `findNavController().navigate(action)` from the Android Navigation Library, to archive a more complex animation than I can do with using `app:enterAnim` in the navigation graph

To archive this I tried to overwrite the enter and exit transition in the Fragment's onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    enterTransition = getEnterTransitionSet()
    exitTransition = getExitTransitionSet()
    allowEnterTransitionOverlap = false
}

 private fun getEnterTransitionSet(): TransitionSet {
    return TransitionSet()
        .addTransition(Fade(Fade.MODE_IN)
            .addTarget(R.id.button)
            .setDuration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        )
        .addTransition(Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
            .addTarget(R.id.text)
            .setDuration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        ).setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER)
}

private fun getExitTransitionSet(): TransitionSet {
    return TransitionSet()
        .addTransition(Fade(Fade.MODE_OUT)
            .addTarget(R.id.buttom)
            .setDuration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        )
        .addTransition(Slide(Gravity.TOP)
            .addTarget(R.id.text)
            .setDuration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        ).setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER)
}
```

The text should slide in from the bottom and slide out to the top, while the button should fade in or out.

To test this i created a loop and navigated to the same fragment all over again on button click, but the enter animation gets never executed and the new fragment gets inflated on top of the old. After that the exit transition of the old fragment gets executed.

My expectation was a behaviour similar to `app:enterAnim` and `app:exitAnim`. And executing the enter transition of the new fragment after the exit transition of the previous fragment. Did I missed something or this not possible?